# Ionic carousel resize issue with $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a plugin in Ionic to create a carousel (https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular-swiper) which has a demo with a simple repeat. I replaced the repeat with my own using $http and it has created a problem in that the delay loading the images causes the slider to break until it is resized. the HTML looks like this:

```
<ks-swiper-container autoplay="500" initial-slide="1" speed="5000" loop="false" show-nav-buttons="false" slides-per-view="2" space-between="20" pagination-clickable="false" override-parameters="{effect: 'coverflow',coverflow: {rotate: 0,stretch: 0,depth: 100,modifier: 1,centeredSlides: true,slideShadows : false}}" on-ready="onReadySwiper(swiper)">

            <ks-swiper-slide class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="feature in featured track by feature.id">
                <img imageonload="" ng-src="{{feature.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url}}" width="100%">
                <h6 ng-bind-html="feature.title"></h6>
            </ks-swiper-slide>

           <ks-swiper-slide class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="img/more.png" style="transform: rotate(180deg);" width="100%">
            <h6>Read More</h6>
            </ks-swiper-slide>

        </ks-swiper-container>
```

I am calling my images from my factory like this:

```
.controller('SwipeCtrl', function($scope, Featured) {

    $scope.swiper = {};
    $scope.onReadySwiper = function (swiper) {

        swiper.on('slideChangeStart', function () {
        });

        swiper.on('onSlideChangeEnd', function () {
        });   

    };




  $scope.featured = [];
  Featured.all().then(function (response,swiper){

      $scope.featured = response;
      for (var i =0; i < $scope.featured.length; i++) {
            $scope.featured[i].date = new Date($scope.featured[i].date);

        }
  }, 

  function (err) {
     if(window.localStorage.getItem("featured") !== undefined) {

      }
    }
  );
})
```

I have tried adding a $timeout but it did not help. I found a suggestion to create a directive:

```
.directive('imageonload', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('load', function() {
                $timeout(function(){
                    $rootScope.swiper.updateSlidesSize();
                });
            });


        }
    };
});
```

But I keep getting "updateSlidesSize() is undefined".

Really not too sure how to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. One of the first things I noticed is that my version of swiper.js (not angular-swiper.js) did not have the function updateSlidesSize(). So I found a newer version of swiper.js and it has that function included.

So that should take care of the undefined. Now, bringing it all together, here's what I did:

```
//My HTML
<ks-swiper-container initial-slide="1"  loop="false" show-nav-buttons="false" slides-per-view="3" space-between="5" pagination-clickable="false" on-ready="onReadySwiper(swiper)">...</ks-swiper-container>

//My controller
$scope.swiper = {}; //initialize
$scope.onReadySwiper = function (swiper)
{
  $scope.swiper = swiper; //update when the swiper is ready
};
$scope.myData=[1,2,3,4,5];
$http.jsonp(myurl+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data)
{
   $scope.myData=data; //e.g.: [6,7,8]
   $timeout(function() //give the data a moment to propagate
   {
     $scope.swiper.updateSlidesSize(); //now run the sizing update - can also use just .update()
     $scope.swiper.slideTo(0); //show the slider from the beginning
   }, 300);
});
```

I have only tested this in Google Chrome with emulation - not on an actual mobile device.